# Remove duplicate rows from DataTable with condition - C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, datatable

I have a datatable as below

```
StudentID  Marks 
 AAA        NULL
 AAA        100
 BBB        200
```

I have to remove the row from datatable by checking studentID in a condition that

1. If there are same studentID then remove row with NULL value and display only student id with value.
2. If both marks are NULL of that student then show only one row.

Resulted Datatable should be

```
StudentID  Marks 
 AAA        100
 BBB        200
```

I have tried to remove duplicate rows from above table using below function

```
     public DataTable RemoveDuplicateRows(DataTable dTable, string colName)
    {
        Hashtable hTable = new Hashtable();
        ArrayList duplicateList = new ArrayList();

        //Add list of all the unique item value to hashtable, which stores combination of key, value pair.
        //And add duplicate item value in arraylist.
        foreach (DataRow drow in dTable.Rows)
        {
            if (hTable.Contains(drow[colName])&& drow["Marks"]==null)
            {
                duplicateList.Add(drow);
            }
            else
            {
                hTable.Add(drow[colName], string.Empty);
            }
        }

        //Removing a list of duplicate items from datatable.
        foreach (DataRow dRow in duplicateList)
            dTable.Rows.Remove(dRow);

        //Datatable which contains unique records will be return as output.
        return dTable;
    }
```

Comment: Also pay attention to the difference between _datatable_ and _datatables_ tags. The second one has no place in this question

Comment: Point 3 makes no sense.  Is this purely arbitrary?

Comment: Instead of using foreach loops, why not create a list of object and use linq to match your conditions and then create a datatable out of it?

Comment: Your code makes no attempt to delete according to your conditions.  It deletes second and subsequent entries, leaving the first, regardless of which one should be kept.

Comment: @JonathanWillcock Point 2 is working as my code.

Comment: @user2431727 Are you strict to manipulate data in datatable , it can be easily achieved at database end?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
DataTable datatabble = new DataTable();
datatabble.Columns.Add("studentid", typeof(string));
datatabble.Columns.Add("marks", typeof(int));

datatabble.Rows.Add("AAA");
datatabble.Rows.Add("AAA",100);
datatabble.Rows.Add("BBB",200);

var duplicates = datatabble.AsEnumerable().GroupBy(r => r[0]).Where(gr => gr.Count() > 1)
            .Select(dupl => dupl.Key).ToList();

var result = datatabble.AsEnumerable().Where(x => 
        (
           (duplicates.Contains(x[0]) && !string.IsNullOrEmpty(x[1].ToString()))
           || !duplicates.Contains(x[0])
        )           
        ).ToList();
```

Output: You can see output with 2 row count with filtered null value.

[image]